# How to convert string to a list of integers?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I would like to be able to input a sequence of integers on one line, such as:

```
97, 128, 125, 17, 2
```

and have the Haskell program convert the input into a list of integers, such as:

```
[97, 128, 135, 17, 2]
```

so that I can do some math operations like `zipWith`(ing) the list with another list of integers.  Having trouble with this. I tried using the `read` and `words` functions but I wasn't able to achieve the expected result. Any ideas?

Comment: I imagine the commas are what's causing your problem. Perhaps think about how you might work around that.

Comment: The next time instead of saying "yes I've tried using `read` but it didn't help" could you post the code you actually wrote? Even if it isn't correct or it doesn't compile it would be helpful and shows you did some research. Moreover we can try to help the problem in your solution instead of simply providing you the code that we would wrote (I'd probably do both things, so by not including actual code you are simply losing possible useful information from the answers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with only using `words` is that the comma (`,`) will still be included.

A *quick-and-dirty* hack is probably to first map all characters instead of digits to a space:

```
import Data.Char(isDigit)

cnv x | isDigit x = x
      | otherwise = ' '
```

and then use:

```
map read . words . map cnv :: Read b => [Char] -> [b]
```

**demo**

```
*Main> ((map read . words . map cnv) "97, 128, 125, 17, 2" :: [Int]
[97,128,125,17,2]
```

A potential problem is of course that you omit `[A-z]` characters, etc. Furthermore this approach is not the most efficient.

An advantage is that by using `read` all items that can be `read` are still candidates to process the stream of "words".

> **Why not filtering?**
>
> One can also use a filter evidently to obtain for instance only spaces and digits. For instance
>
> ```
> map read . words . filter (\x -> isDigit x || isSpace x)
> ```
>
> A potential problem is that it is possible that the numbers are not separated by spaces ( ), but only by commas (`,`), semi-colons (`;`), etc. Working with the above expression generates the correct result:
>
> ```
> (map read . words . filter (\x -> isDigit x || isSpace x)) "97, 128, 125, 17, 2" :: [Int]
> [97,128,125,17,2]
> ```
>
> but
>
> ```
> (map read . words . filter (\x -> isDigit x || isSpace x)) "97,128,125,17,2" :: [Int]
> [97128125172]
> ```
>
> doesn't.

Comment: That elegantly solves the problem.  Many thanks.  (Now I'll just have to figure out how it works :-)

Answer (score 6):

One possible (again, quick'n'dirty) solution is to use `read` with the instance defined for lists, which expects strings in the format `[item1, item2, item3...]`:

```
convert :: String -> [Int]
convert s = read $ "[" ++ s ++ "]"
```

A more robust solution would be parsing with `filter` or similar (as shown in the other answer) or using a parsing library to do the job properly.

Comment: The only two possible problems I see with this solution are (a) users using other separators making it more sensitive to errors, and (b) the fact that the function is not as generic as doing a memberwise read. But +1 btw (so definitely no offense).

Comment: @CommuSoft Well, since the type is monomorphic I don't see how (b) is an issue. Can you provide an example input (formatted as in the question) that is parsed by your solution but not by this one? Point (a) is reasonable but then it depends on the purpose (e.g. if you are parsing something according to a public standard format so you know this wont suddenly change in two days you could simply do the above without troubles; when the standard is updated you have to change the code to support the new version in any case, so not much increased work).

Comment: @Bakuriu: say for instance you want to modify the reader to allow square brackets as well `[`, `]`. And now you wish to read something with `"a]"` being a valid item to parse, then it is possible that one cannot make the distiction between the closing of the array bracket, or part of the item. But as said before, this is a bit being picky. No offense against this answer ;). Depending on how the `read` works, reading `"[a]"` can result in an error for parsing it as "[ a]" or it can read `"[ a ] ]"` (where the closing bracket should be attached to `a`.

Comment: @CommuSoft Well yes, a solution for this problem might not be a solution for a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

The task you're specifying falls under the category of textual parsing. When facing such a problem the safe bet is to approach it with either the "parsec" or the "attoparsec" library. Those libraries provide APIs which abstract over parsing in a safe and composable (hence scalable) way.

Here's how you'd write the "attoparsec" parser for your task:

```
listOfInts :: Parser [Int]
listOfInts =
  sepBy decimal separator
  where
    separator =
      skipSpace *> char ',' *> skipSpace
```

Note that the provided implementation already allows you to parse a not well formed input, where the separator might have multiple or no spaces before and after the comma. Also note how simple it is to express this already complicated condition using such a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. For my application, this seems to work well:

```
myInput <- getLine
```

> 123 23 345 23

```
(map read . words) myInput::[Int]
```

I was having a little trouble understanding why the parenthesis go where they do, but this seems to work also:

```
myInput <- getLine
```

234 34 235 465 34

```
map read $ words myInput::[Int]
```

Since I'm just using spaces to separate the numbers, I don't have to use the filter, but thanks for posting it because now I understand the syntax better.

Don